# How to update table with BindingSource?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have datagridview with datasource from BindingSource, after editing this table I need to update it But its not updating. I am using NpgsqlDataAdapter, to update it, but it shows me an error: 
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'."

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the grid to a DataTable type.

Cant´you create a DataSet, then fill it with the information you need?, and then use the resulting DataTable to bind it to the DataSource.

Comment: Did it work?, don´t forget to close your questions and accept the answer if it is correct.